# No sound with Chromium snap

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, snap, chromium

Recently, my computer "upgraded" the Chromium deb-package to a snap on its own. 
Not that I had wanted it, I had in fact uninstalled snapcraft. 
I have read of this latest crap move by Canonical, so I was not surprised when snap reinstalled itself (unwantedly and without asking). 
But so far, it seemed to be working, so I didn't mind (after having blocked snap-refreshes on metered-connections).

However, I just wanted to watch a china-uncensored youtube video 
5 seconds ago - and - **no sound**... 
The sound is working. System sounds work, vlc has sound, and with Firefox, sound works, too. 
It used to work with the Chromium deb-package as well.

This seems to be a snap issue. 
Is there any way I can debug this ? 
Any way to view whatever log file to find out what goes wrong ? 
Or any ideas towards problem resolution ?

(I'm running KDE-Plasma as root, so /usr/bin/pulseaudio runs with --system - I suspect that might be the problem)

Comment: IMO switch to Firefox.  The Ubuntu community has decided it is not worth the time to be forced to constantly audit a browser (a LOT of work) from a developer that ultimately is not really prioritized with open source and freedom.  The community can better allocate resources.  See: https://ubuntu.com/blog/chromium-in-ubuntu-deb-to-snap-transition

Comment: @Nmath: I'm already doing this with Firefox Developer Edition :)

Comment: Is Google Chrome not an option? If not, there is this link for installing Chromium via alternate sources (from Mint, which disables snapd on install): https://linuxmint-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chromium.html

Comment: Remove the snap version and install the .deb version. I have directions [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/snap-application-error/1371/3?u=kgiii) if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug/feature in the snap version of chromium: even if you unset XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, it re-sets it when it runs, causing problems with pulseaudio if you're not using the standard XDG settings (this can be confirmed by looking in /proc//environ). Installing the latest Google Chrome (not Chromium) seems to fix this issue, so it looks like snap is doing something that it shouldn't.